# Using RMI with JSF and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, rmi

I want to write a simple application using RMI. On the server side I have an interface foo and a class fooImpl.
My interface is:

```
import java.rmi.Remote;

public interface Foo extends Remote {
   public String exec(String test) throws Exception;
}
```

My implementation of the the above interface is:

```
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class FooImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Foo {

    public FooImpl() throws Exception {
        java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        java.rmi.Naming.rebind("myFoo",this);
    }

    public String exec(String test) {
        return "This is a Test";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FooImpl fooImpl = new FooImpl();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On the client side, I have web application using PrimeFace which is runnig on Tomcat. There is a IndexBean on client side:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class IndexBean {

    public void execute() {
        try {
            Foo foo = (Foo) java.rmi.Naming.lookup("//localhost/myFoo");
            System.out.println(foo.exec());
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

when I execute the code, I get the following error at the client side:

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested
>   exception is:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Foo (no security
>   manager: RMI class loader disabled)   at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)   at
>   bean.IndexBean.execute(IndexBean.java:15)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:88)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:51)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:409)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:103)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1013)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:284)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1302)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:745)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Foo (no security manager: RMI class
>   loader disabled)  at
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:553)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:255)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1558)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>     ... 44 more

Also, I changed the port which Tomcat uses to do not have conflict with RMI port.

Comment: This problem is more about Java and RMI. JSF is irrelevant for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The client doesn't have the remote interface on its CLASSPATH, or, probably, the stub either. To avoid using a stub, add

```
super(0);
```

as the first line of the constructor.

NB you must store the result of `createRegistry()` in a static variable, to prevent the Registry from exiting.

Comment: The client has the Foo interface, too. I, also, created a jar file from the Foo interface and put it in lib folder in WEB-INF but there was no change. I added "super(0);" to FooImpl's constructor but nothing changed.

Comment: The client doesn't have `Foo`. The exception says so.